# Expose dependencies of a standalone component

Tags: angular

[Reproduction on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jcjsgp?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

All the components are standalone.

I have a form-field component that uses an input directive. I would like to import the directive when I import the component, without having to explicitly import it. Kind of like how modules work, except in standalone mode.

Is it possible, and if so, how ?

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FieldComponent, InputDirective], // ← Remove the directive from here
  template: `
    <app-field>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Some text">
    </app-field>
  `,
})
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-field',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [InputDirective],
  template: '<ng-content select="input"></ng-content>',
  styleUrls: ['./field.component.css'],
})
```

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'app-field input',
  standalone: true,
})
export class InputDirective {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Here I am');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw a [tweet about this](https://twitter.com/synalx/status/1684787489779970048) from Alex Rickabaugh (member of the angular team) :

> Short answer: don't - the point of standalone is that deps are
> imported individually and not bundled.
>
> Nuanced answer: if you have directives that work together and need to
> be added together, use an NgModule.
>
> Technical answer: `[HlmAccordion, ...] as const` should work

So in your case you're better of sticking to ngModules.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a Twitter/X account, so I cannot see the thread. But noted, thanks ! Could you just specify WHERE this `as const` should be written ?

Comment: right after the array  `const myImports = [HlmAccordion, ...] as const`. It's a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround for this type of imports (there are similar use-cases with services) that I have found is to use an array:

```
export const FIELD_IMPORTS = [FieldComponent, InputDirective];

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ...FIELD_IMPORTS],
  template: `
    <app-field>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Some text">
    </app-field>
  `,
})
```

Comment: As you said, it's a workaround, and one I'm not liking at all (personal preference)

Comment: I don't think that you have any other choice unfortunately.

Comment: Sticking to modules it is then !